# DocuSign - Is it possible to add the signers title (value) to the envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign REST API to create an envelope along with the signers.  Looking at the API you can provide the signers name and email so when the signer receives this document to sign and goes into DocuSign to sign the document the 'name' 'placeholder' is already filled in with the name that was provided in the Signer block.  Is there any way to add other 'placeholder' values about the signer, like 'title' so when they go to sign those 'placeholders' are already filled in (user could update the value if they choose)?

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create#signer

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use TextTabs to prepopulate field with any value and if you are not marked that field as ReadOnly then Signer will have option to update that value. You cannot prepopulate value using TitleTabs, so it is better to user TextTab with tabLabel as Title and then prepopulate value in this TextTab.

Comment: Can TextTabs have a different value per signer?  For example if the envelope is to be signed by 3 different signers can the prepopulated value be different for each signer or does it have to be the same value?  Thank you.

Comment: Each Tab is assigned to each Signer, so if you need unique value for each signer, then create each tab for each signer, and prepopulate value in each tab